# Can't show player controls on iOS lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I've a problem to show player controls on the lock screen (iOS 11.2). What I've already done is the following:

In AppDelegate.swift I initialized the AVAudioSession:

```
import MediaPlayer

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

Then my app consists of a TabHostController with several views. One of them is the audio tab. There I try to handle the remote buttons:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import MediaPlayer

class AudioTabViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
      self.audioPlayClicked()
      return .success
    }
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
      self.audioPauseClicked()
      return .success
    }
    commandCenter.stopCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
      self.audioStopClicked()
      return .success
    }
  }
}
```

And finally I added the backgrond modes to Info.plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

What happens? I can build the project without any problems and run it on an iPhone 8. My music is played.
But there are no audio controls on the lock screen (screen is empty).
And if I look into the iOS control center then I find some audio controls but by clicking the play button there, only a track of Apple's music app is played which I used anytime before.
So I think that my app is not system-wide "registered" as the current audio player.

Answer (score 7):

I do not know you solve the problem but maybe someone has some problem and this post help them.

I had the same problem and

I finally found the problem,

When i was setting up AVAudioSession, I was using this line->
try

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers)
```

once I changed that line to the following, lock screen controls displayed and worked fine ->

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])
```

So i guess the problem was passing in an argument for AVAudioSessionCategoryPlaybackOptions . I tried passing in .duckOthers and .mixWithOthers and in both cases it causes the lock screen controls to not display at all

Comment: You've just saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it for me too, but I'd still like to configure the audio session to duck other audio (and interrupt spoken word). How can I achieve that?